# Symmetric difference of 3 sets question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am tryig to solve the following problem : ( *I am using the $\oplus$ as a replacement for the triangle symbol of the Symmetric difference)

if $A^c {\oplus}B = A \oplus C$ then $ C = B^c $

and I don't  even have a clue how to start to solve this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ease of notation I'll use just $+$ for the operator (the triangle mentioned, and circled plus in other verion used).

Some facts about $+$ needed: It is associative and commutative, and if $U$ is the universal set and $\emptyset$ the empty set, then $$A+A=\emptyset,\   A+A^c=U,\ A+U=A^c,\ A+\emptyset=A.
$$
Here $A^c$ is complement, and associativity and these rules can be shown fairly easily from the definition of $+.$

Starting from $A^c+B=A+C,$ operate on both sides by adding ($+A$) to each. We arrive using the above rules at $U+B=\emptyset+C.$ Then $U+B=B^c,\ \emptyset + C=C,$ giving the desired $B^c=C.$

Comment: J.-E. Pin...My answer was being typed when yours came in, basically same.

Answer (score 1):

> and I don't even have a clue how to start to solve this question

Start with the *definition* of symmetric difference.

$$A^\complement\oplus C = (A^\complement\cap C^\complement)\cup(A\cap C)\\A\oplus B=(A^\complement\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^\complement)$$

This suggests a Proof By Cases.

- Assume $A^\complement\oplus C=A\oplus B$
- Prove $\forall x~.(x\in C\iff x\notin B)$ by considering the cases $x\in A$ and $x\notin A$.

$\quad\vdots$

- Conclude: if $A^\complement\oplus C=A\oplus B$ then $C=B^\complement$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A, B,C$ be subsets of $E$.
If $A^c \oplus B = A \oplus C$, then $$A \oplus A^c \oplus B = A \oplus A \oplus C.$$ 
Now, since $A \oplus A^c = E$ and $E \oplus B = B^c$, one has $A \oplus A^c \oplus B = B^c$. Furthermore, since $A \oplus A =\emptyset$ and $\emptyset\oplus C = C$, one has $A \oplus A \oplus C = C$. Thus $C = B^c$.